# Add a line and turn this into a sport

Tags: visual, rebus

Add a straight line to this visual and turn it into a sport.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

May add a line as

> [image: Add an L at the start]

which may be read as

> lacrosse

Comment: +[lateral-thinking] :)

Comment: Good catch on the [rebus] tag.

Comment: @Pumbaa using https://rot13.com/ g znl or ernq nf pebff